# Visual C# Beginner Empty Project Help?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm a beginner to Visual Studio, I can create Windows From Projects and Console Projects just fine, but I can't compile Empty Projects,

The steps I take are:

1. Create an Empty Project.
2. Add a class, add a reference to System and System.Windows.Forms
3. Put the following code in the class:

   > ```
   > using System;
   > using System.Collections.Generic;
   > using System.Linq;
   > using System.Text;
   > using System.Windows.Forms;
   >
   > namespace Circles
   > {
   >     class Program
   >     {
   >         static void Main(string[] args)
   >         {
   >             MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
   >
   >         }
   >     }
   > }
   > ```

Then I hit compile, and it gives me this error:

> Error 1   Program 'D:\C #\Projects\Circles\Circles\obj\x86\Debug\Circles.exe' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point Circles

The Properties build action is set to compile, but the Startup Object in the Project roperties is not set, is this causing the problem, if so what can I do?

EDIT: Question resolved see CharithJ's answer below.
Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`main` method name should be `Main`

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Circles 
{ 
    public class Program 
    { 
        public static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yup, it works thank you very much, could you please explain what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @Suleman : I added public for both class and Main method. And changed the main as Main. That's it. Couple of simple issues.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the `public` access modifier to the class and the main method, and make main begin with an upper-case m:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");

    }
}
```

Edit: As per comments, neither public access modifier is actually required.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the 'Startup Object' to be your `Program` class.

Windows applications (that is applications with an output type of 'Windows Application') typically have an entry point that looks like this:

```
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new SomeForm());
    }
```

Whilst a 'Console Application' will typically have an entry such as:

```
    public static void Main(string[] arguments)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: You don't have to set the startup object as long as you have a single unambiguous Main method.

Comment: @Øyvind: in which case the correct answer is probably the capitalization, which I overlooked.

Comment: It is. I overlooked it as well ;)

Comment: Nope, capitaliztion doesn't work (I already had it capitalized, but somehow messed it up while posting here)

Answer (score 3):

Change `static void main(string[] args)` to `public static void Main(string[] args)`.

Its `Main` not `main`. Uppercase `M`.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I have the main in uppercase in the  program, don't know how I messed it up here, but it still gives the same error

Answer (score 2):

change to

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

(captial 'M')

You don't need to make it public.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any specific reason why you don't use the Windows Form application template in Visual Studio?